# Alternating Projections with constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, projection

I am struggling with the following alternating projection theorem tasks.

$ C_1$ , $C_2$ - closed convex subsets in $R^d$, their intersection is not empty.

$x_0 \in C$, and sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ is defined as
$x_{n+1} = P_{C_1}P_{C_2}x_n$

Find $x^* \in R^d$ s.t: $||x^*|| \leq r, r>0$ and $Ax^* = y$,

where $A \in R^{k \times d}$, $k<d$, rank $A = k$

I need to write maths algorithm using the alternating projections theorem.

I have started by writing down a Lagrangian for the problem but got stuck at the formulation. Thanks in advance for some hints!

Comment: What are your sets $C_1, C_2$? Is $C_1 = \{\mathbf{x} | \|\mathbf{x}\|\leq r\}$ and $C_2 = \{\mathbf{x} | A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}\}$? Or do you need to satisfy the two conditions above + two more conditions?

Comment: $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed convex subsets in $R^d$. The first element of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, $x_0 \in C_1$

Comment: Then what you're saying is that there are 4 convex sets, $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ and you're trying to find a point $\mathbf{x}^*$ that belongs to the intersection $C = C_1\cap C_2\cap C_3\cap C_4$?

Comment: No, there are just two convex sets $C_1$, $C_2$ and I am trying to find a point $x^*$ that belongs to the intersection $C_1 ∩ C_2$

Comment: What about the conditions $\|\mathbf{x}\|\leq r$ and $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$?

Comment: These are the constraints on solution

Comment: Therefore we can view them as sets as well. What you will need to do is consecutively project a vector onto each of these sets until convergence. What exactly are you required to do and what have you tried so fat?